# avoid - aggregation in ag-grid

Tags: javascript, typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

i have ag-grid. This is the column structure -

account share qty

i'm grouping by account (rowGroup = true). I have this sample data -

| account | share | qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 234 | xny | 4 |
| 234 | ghy | 3 |

this appears as

| account | share | qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 234 |  | 0 |
|  | xny | 4 |
|  | ghy | 3 |

note that 0 comes for qty. this is because i havenot provided any aggregateFunction to colDef.
I want that qty cell to be empty for group level records (instead of showing a zero). is there a way to do it?

Comment: Could you please try pasting what you've tried so far ?

Comment: hello, i don't have the code for this on my home laptop. i came across this question while working on job. since i don't have code, i tried to describe the problem as much as i could in the description. i have also found a solution that works for me, see my answer below for this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the correct way but I was able to solve this by checking if the row is a group level row in my value formatter.

if the row is a group level row, i would return an empty string. otherwise, i would invoke the formatting function to show formatted data.